# How do I use sed for selective replacement of certain lines

Tags: linux, bash, text, sed

I have text as follows in file:

```
Line 1
Line 2
WORD1
Line3
Line 4
WORD2
Line5
```

I would like to replace all lines between WORD1 and WORD2 to produce final output:

```
Line 1
Line 2
NEW
LINES
XXXXX
Line5
```

With `sed '/WORD1/,/WORD2/d' input.txt` I can remove the lines, but how can I replace them instead of deleting them?

Comment: try `sed '/WORD1/,/WORD2/{s/.*/foo/}' file`

Comment: @AvinashRaj that will print the same thing for every line between. Try `sed '/WORD1/{:1;N;/WORD2/!b1;s/.*/foo/}'`

Answer (score 1):

One way:

Replacement text file:

```
$ cat rep
NEW
LINES
XXXXX
```

Input file:

```
$ cat file
Line 1
Line 2
WORD1
Line3
Line 4
WORD2
Line5
```

sed command:

```
$ sed '/WORD1/,/WORD2/{
> /WORD2/r rep
> d
> }' file
```

The sed command seraches for the line range WORD1 till WORD2 and deletes those lines(d) , and when WORD2 is encounterd, it dumps the replacement file contents(r rep).

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/WORD1/,/WORD2/c\NEW\nLINES\nXXXXX' file
```

This uses the range match and the `c` (change) command.

Answer (score 0):

If awk is ok, then try this:

```
awk '/WORD1/{p=1; print "NEW\nLINES\nXXXXX"}; !p; /WORD2/{p=0}' file
```